# How to access other attributes/columns from a parse.com object after pulling the object from parse (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I am pulling code from parse using the query below. I retrieve the objects but I can only access "object.objectId" if I try "object.name" and "name" is a column on the Funlists table my app crashes and I get this error: "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1286_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "FunLists")
        query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

                // Do something with the found objects
                for object in objects {
                    NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
                    self.funlists.append(object.name)


                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to access to the entity properties using dictionary-like syntax, like:

```
object["name"]
```

I presume that the error happens here:

```
self.funlists.append(object.name)
```

I would change that to:

```
self.funlists.append(object["name"])
```

or

```
self.funlists.append(object["name"] as String)
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio! "object["name"] as String" worked I will accept your answer soon, stackoverflow said I have to wait 8 mins. LOL